# How to extract the superscript or subscript data in excel with python？

Tags: python, excel, format, data-processing

I wanna to **analysis chemical formula data** in excel with python. Beacause excel data already have the format to distinguish charge or atomic number, so I don't need to interpret it de novo. But I met with some difficulties when I read it with python.

[image]

`pandas`, `xlrd`, `openpyxl`, even `python-docx`, none of them could read data with superscript distinguished. It all be deemed as plain text. And it seems that the format of superscript or subscript cannot be directly matched.

How could I do to finish my task without interpreting it de novo? No matter python or any other data processing tools is ok.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Even Excel itself won't preserve the superscripting if you use the value of the cell in a formula that is elsewhere in the workbook. That is because Excel considers the superscripting to be markup on the cell, not on the data.

Comment: Take a look at LaTeX. Have you tried reading data in unicode? There are few python latex parsers available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to express complex formula is through LaTex, python has a module called PyLaTex.

However, it may not read Mircrosoft Format of Formulas. You may need to search a translate program/site to translate a formula written in *.doc to Latex script. - i.e.
https://www.grindeq.com/
https://www.docx2latex.com/

Comment: `Ag_{2}C_{2}O_{4}+2e═2Ag+C_{2}O_{4}^{2-}`

Comment: That's very helpful to solve my problem, and I could go on my work :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to open your file in Python, format it and save it into excel and then redo your analysis.
So this is what I mean.
first open file and put each line in a list
Then do a for loop and convert various subscripts and superscripts into something that distinguishable. Below is a sample code.

```
    import csv
    csvfile = open('file.csv')
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    dictList = []
    
    for line in reader: dictList.append(line)
    
    csvfile.close()

# Making the modifications inside our list, which 
   contains
# a dictionary for each line in the CSV.

for line in dictList:
    for key in line:
        line[key] = line[key].replace('\\', '\\\\')
        line[key] = line[key].replace('#', '\\#')
        line[key] = line[key].replace('_', '\\_')
        line[key] = line[key].replace('&', '\\&')

    # Writing the new lines to a new file.
    
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
        fieldnames = ['Field 1', 'Field 2', 'Field 3']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, 
     fieldnames=fieldnames)
    
        writer.writeheader()
        for line in dictList:
         writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the excel sheet is my orginal data to standardize, and I need to extract data form excel.